# If $\sigma$ takes squares to squares, conclude $a < b$ implies $\sigma a < \sigma b$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Prove that any $\sigma \in $ Aut$(\mathbb{R/\mathbb{Q}})$ takes squares to squares and takes positive reals to positive reals. Conclude that $a < b$ implies $\sigma a < \sigma b$ ,$\forall a,b 
\in R$.

proof: Suppose $\sigma: a → b$, such that $a = c^2$ where $b$ is a square. 
Then $\sigma(a) = \sigma(c^2) = \sigma(c *c) = \sigma (c) \sigma(c) = (\sigma(c))^2$ which is a square. So it takes positive reals to positive reals.
Then suppose that if $a < b$ , where $a, b\in R$.

Then there is a $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $a < q < b$. So $q = \sigma q = \sigma ( q + a - a) =  \sigma (q - a) + \sigma a > \sigma a.$

So $q > \sigma(a)$.

And $q = \sigma (q) = \sigma (q + b - b) = \sigma( q + b ) - \sigma (-b)$

can someone please help  me with $q < \sigma(b)$? and please verify I am on the right track. Anything could help thank you !

Comment: In your last equation, you should have $\sigma(q+b)-\sigma(b)$, not $\sigma(q+b)-\sigma(-b)$.

Comment: I really don’t understand the difficulty. Knowing that $\sigma$ takes squares to squares, you know that if $a\ge0$ then $\sigma(a)\ge0$. Consequently, if $a\le b$ (so that $b-a\ge0$), it follows that $\sigma(a)\le\sigma(b)$ (because $\sigma(b)-\sigma(a)=\sigma(b-a)\ge0$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of splitting $\sigma(q+b-b)$ as $\sigma(q+b)-\sigma(b)$, split it as $\sigma(q-b)+\sigma(b)=-\sigma(b-q)+\sigma(b)$.  Since $b>q$, $\sigma(b-q)>0$, so you get $\sigma(q)<\sigma(b)$.

(Actually, you can do this without introducing $q$ at all!  Just notice that $\sigma(b)=\sigma(a+b-a)=\sigma(a)+\sigma(b-a)$, and $\sigma(b-a)>0$.)

Comment: So if we don't use $q$ , then we have $\sigma(b - a) > 0$ because we assume $a < b$. So $\sigma(b) > \sigma (a)$. ?

Comment: if we show it without the $q$ , then just by that we can conclude $\sigma a < \sigma b$. Which is much faster than introducing $q$.

Comment: Yep!  And if you think about it, what your argument with $q$ is doing is just making that same argument twice to separately show that $\sigma(a)<\sigma(q)$ and $\sigma(q)<\sigma(b)$.  You don't actually need the fact that $q=\sigma(q)$.

Answer (score 1):

You are right for the part $1$ of the problem.

Now note that any positive real $r$  is square of some real number say $s$ i.e. $r= s^2$and by part $1$ $\sigma$ carries squares to squares so $\sigma (r)=(\sigma (s ))^2$ which  will be a positive real number.